# First element in a while loop?

Tags: php, loops, csv, while-loop, fgetcsv

I am writing a PHP script that imports a csv and inserts into a table but i need to get the first row so i can have the field names..here is my csv

```
id  artist          song           
11  NewBee          great stuff
10  anotherNewbee   even better   
6    NewArtist       New song
```

As you can see the first row is the name of the fields that i need. here is my loop

```
$handle = fopen('csvs/'.$_FILES["csv"]["name"], 'r');

while (($data = fgetcsv($handle, 1000, ',')) !== FALSE) {
 print_r($data); 
 //do something with it but i need the first time around 


 array(3) { [0]=> string(2) "id" [1]=> string(6) "artist" [2]=> string(4) "song" } 
 array(3) { [0]=> string(2) "11" [1]=> string(6) "NewBee" [2]=> string(1) "great stuff" }  
 array(3) { [0]=> string(2) "10" [1]=> string(13) "anotherNewbee" [2]=> string(1) "even better"}
```

How do i get the first and put them in variables and continue the loop of the data using those fields in an insert statement

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Would this work for you?

```
$row = 1;

while (($data = fgetcsv($handle, 1000, ',')) !== FALSE) {
    if($row == 1) {
        // do something
    }
    else
    {
        // do something
    }

    ++$row;
}
```

Comment: Use Markdown to format your posts so your code is more readable (I've done that for you). [This page shows how.](http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help)

Answer (score 4):

Prior to your while block, just run the fgetcsv function a single time and store the field headings.

Comment: +1 Of course, a simple `!== false` check should be implemented for that just in case the first line isn't in CSV column format. With that in place the while loop can also be completely skipped if the file isn't CSV.

Answer (score 2):

Either deepsat's or mattmoon9's methods will work fine. Here's what [mattmoon9's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4074470/first-element-in-a-while-loop/4074498#4074498) would look like structured in code (also based on my comment on the answer):

```
$handle = fopen('csvs/'.$_FILES["csv"]["name"], 'r');

if (($columns = fgetcsv($handle, 1000, ',')) !== false) {
    while (($data = fgetcsv($handle, 1000, ',')) !== false) {
        // Process data
    }

    // Insert into database using $columns as table column names
} else {
    // The file couldn't be parsed as CSV
}
```